# outlook mail window with pre populated to sender box not working

Tags: javascript, php, function, outlook

[errors i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O1bd.png)

I have a table that contains details one of this being emails. When i click a link i have outlook mail opening but i want to take the email of that row in the table and put it into the 'to' part of the email. Below i have code for what i am currently doing.

the code below displays the data from my database in a table format

```html
 <table class="table table-striped custab">
           <thead>
            <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Booking ID</th>
     <th> Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>time</th>
     <th>No. of guests</th>
            <th>Booking Reason</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
     <th width="110" class="ac">Approved?</th>
     </tr> 
           <thead>
             <!-- php function to only select the bookings that have not yet been approved/rejected -->
             <?php
  include 'config.php';
  $select = "SELECT * FROM `booking` WHERE `status`IS NULL ";
  $result = $conn->query($select);
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
      ?>
            <tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['customer_ID'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['booking_date'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['booking_time'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['attendee_no'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['booking_reason'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['comments'] ?></td>
                
                <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:TriggerOutlook(<?php echo $row['Email'];?>)" value="submit">Email this Codesnippet</a></a>
            </td>
            
            
            </tr>
                 <?php
             }
  ?>
        </table>
```

The function below gets the pop up to display for outlook mail

```html
<script  type="text/javascript"> TriggerOutlook(Email)

    {    
    
  var $to      = 'Email';
  var body = "your booking has been approved";
        <!-- var body = escape(window.document.title + String.fromCharCode(13)+ window.location.href);        --->

        var subject = "Your booking request";

                        window.location.href = "mailto:?body="+body+"&to="+$to+"&subject="+subject;               

            }   

    </script>
```

if i put in an email manually into the var $to = the outlook pop up works however if i try to take the email from the table it doesnt, can anyone help me out to identity where i am going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.yoast.com/guide-mailto-links/

Answer (score 0):

## 1 You don't need the PHP `$` declaration for variables, thus:

```
var $to      = 'Email';
```

should be:

```
var to      = 'Email';
```

more descriptive variables could make future updates easier:

```
var toAddr      = 'Email';
```

## 2 Your JavaScript function should be preceded with the function tag

```
<script  type="text/javascript"> TriggerOutlook(Email)

{
```

changes to:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"> 
function TriggerOutlook(Email){
```

## 3 Use a button rather than link

Replace 
`<a href="#" onclick="javascript:TriggerOutlook(<?php echo $row['Email'];?>)" value="submit">Email this Codesnippet</a></a>`

With

```
<button 
    onclick="TriggerOutlook(<?php echo $row['Email'];?>)" 
    value="submit"
    >Email this Codesnippet</button>
```

Comment: thank you for that comment , when i click the link nothing is coming up for the outlook mail window do you know why this is?

Comment: Katie, try replacing `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:TriggerOutlook(<?php echo $row['Email'];?>)" value="submit">Email this Codesnippet</a></a>` with `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:TriggerOutlook(<?php echo $row['Email'];?>)" value="submit">Email this Codesnippet</a></a>

Comment: changed it to a button but still nothing

Comment: Did you also update the onclick call, as in my example code?

Comment: yes i replaced my link with the button code you have above

Comment: Is your script being called? See my answer here on how to check if your not sure. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579867/js-send-value-to-input-hidden-html-not-work/54580089#54580089)

Comment: i have added an image into the original question for the errors i get in the console when i press the button

Comment: go to elements to inspect your js. See which line is flagged with the error. It also looks like you must be trying to use JQuery with Bootstrap, but did not properly include jquery. I am not familiar with calling outlook in this manner, and so am only trying to help clean up code errors